# Month wise attendance report Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have an SQL View show data like:

```
EmployeeID :   Employee Name: Present / Absent:     Date: 

0001           ABC                   P          10-09-2015
0001           ABC                   A          11-09-2015
0002           XYX                   A          10-09-2015
0003           XYX                   P          11-09-2015
```

I want report like this:

```
                      10-09-2015         11-09-2015 
0001     ABC            Present           Absent 
0002     XYX            Absent            Present
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Usr cross tab for this kind of requirements... take riw as id and columns as rest of fields

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get the date column grouping(as it can expand dynamically, and how many columns to expand on right is not sure).

If horizontal grouping can be a work around, then please check below.

Try grouping in Crystal Report, and choose date field as an option.
(Insert>Group from toolbar)

That will give you a look like:

```
date1________________________________________

date2________________________________________
```

Now again group by EmployeeID, this will be placed within the existing group, so final look will be:

```
date1________________________________________________
Employee 1 details_____________________________________
Employee 2 details_____________________________________

date2________________________________________________
Employee 1 details_____________________________________
Employee 2 details_____________________________________
```